# AJAX request not returning the right response

Tags: jquery

```
function downloadReport(strUrl, objData) {
    $.ajax({
      url: strDashboardUrl,
      data: objData,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(objResponse, status) {
        // redirect into file for downloading
        window.open(strUrl + "record/DownloadNoteAttachment?note_id=" + objResponse.note_id, '_blank');
        // hide message
        $('.downloadMessage_report').hide();
        // hide modal
        $('#download_report_modal').modal('hide');
      },
      error: function(objError, status) {
        alert("Error downloading File");
      }

    });
  }
```

This is the data the was being passed

```
var objDataAsset = {
    assetTypes: '',
    asset_summary: 1,
    module_name: 'job_sites',
    action: 'DownloadAssetSummary',
    record_id : '',
    only_fails: '',
    pdf: true,
    from_asset_management: true
  };
```

I have this function which performs a POST request, objDataAsset.assetType is an array, if the length of an array is less than 23, the request's result is success which is to download the file but when the objDataAsset.assetType's length exceeds in 23, the request is failing . Is there's something i have to do to the server config ?

Comment: what is the error or failed message ?

Comment: There is no `objDataAsset.assetType` in your example. There is only `assetTypes` and that's a string, not an array. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: My bad, On the process of submission, the assetTypes' value was being filled with the selected Asset Types and each assetTypes was being pushed into the assetTypes attribute.

Comment: There's no failed or error message because the ajax success was being fired.

Comment: The only difference is when the assetTypes data has a length of less than 23, the file was being downloaded, but when greater than 23, the file was not being downloaded.

Comment: @lancedelacruz what is the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: `Response: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>414 Request-URI Too Long</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request-URI Too Long</h1>
<p>The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity
limit for this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>`

Comment: in status the response is success

Answer (score 0):

What is your ajax response type?? is it JSON...
if it is then add

> dataType : 'json'

on your ajax attributes after type

Comment: can you print response

Comment: `Response: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>414 Request-URI Too Long</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request-URI Too Long</h1>
<p>The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity
limit for this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>`

Comment: in status the response is `success`

Comment: your strDashboardUrl seems too long kindly look into it

Comment: can you print the url?

Comment: if the record has a value, the file will downloaded